# how to fix Javascript Invalid Date Error in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, cross-browser

I have a date in format `11-May-16` and would like to create an instance of date using constructor `new Date('11-May-16')`.

However in Internet Explorer and Firefox it is not working.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only formats officially supported by the `Date()` constructor (which calls [`Date.parse(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)) are [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Any other formats are implementation specific and may not be supported cross-browser.

A quick dependency-free way to create a date would be to parse it yourself.  For example, using regexes:

```
function parseDate(date) {
  var MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', ...];
  var date = '11-May-16';
  var match = date.match(/(\d{2})-([A-Za-z]{3})-(\d{2})/);
  return new Date(2000 + parseInt(match[3]), MONTHS.indexOf(match[2]), match[1]);
}

parseDate('11-May-16')
-> Wed May 11 2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Note that the only **official** format supported is a subset of ISO 8601 (see [*EMA-262 §20.3.3.2*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse)).